# Writing label expression with ArcMap and If then Statement?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, if-else

I am having problems with label expression in ArcMap 10.2.1.

I want to show two labels per polygon, but only when there are two labels to show. 
Every polygon has at least one label (Veg_Dominant), but some polygons also have a second (Veg_codominant). I want polygons with only one label to show this one label, and polygons with two labels to show both with a '+' sign in between.

This is how I entered it in the label expression:

[image]

This is how it looks in the map:

[image]

is there a way to only show the '+' sign when there is more than one label to show?

Comment: Click on Help in the lower middle of your label expression dialog. The If-Else statement is one of the examples there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Label Expression, switch to "advanced", select VBScript as Parser, and paste this code:

```
Function FindLabel ( [veg_dominant] , [veg_codominant]  )
if [veg_codominant] <> " " then
  FindLabel = [veg_dominant] + "+" + [veg_codominant]
else
 FindLabel = [veg_dominant]
end if
End Function
```

This expression means: if veg_codominant has values, then the label will be field1+field2, otherwise if the field is empty, use only field1 as the label

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Python version after selecting advanced in Label Expression:

```
def FindLabel ( [veg_dominant] , [veg_codominant]):
    if [veg_codominant] != ' ':
        return [veg_dominant] + "+"+ [veg_codominant]
    else:
        return [veg_dominant]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most pythonic way of doing this is to use `filter` and `str.join` built-in methods, which lets you to add as many fields as you like without worrying about putting delimiters in between and checking if the value is `False`, for example:

```
def FindLabel ([veg_dominant], [veg_codominant]):
    return  "+".join(filter(None, ([veg_dominant], [veg_codominant])))
```